# Charge on parralel cylindrical conductors with reverse current

Tags: charge, conductors

Suppose one has two parralel cylindrical conductors with a distance \$d\$ and an radius of \$\rho\$ while \$\rho \ll d\$.
The currents through the conductors are reverse, but the absolute current is the same.
Now it is stated, that if the charge on one conductor is \$Q\$, due to the reverse currents, the charge on the other conductor would be \$-Q\$.
But how exactly can the current - provided that it is constant - influence the charge on the conductors, as the number of charge carriers (inside a fixed control volume around the conductor) stays the same?

Comment: How is a current impelled? What makes it happen, at all?

Comment: Put the rest of the question context in your question, there is obviously somethig missing

Comment: A surface charge gradient is required for a current to occur. You can work out that gradient from basic physics and some reasoned assumptions about the conduction band. At any point along the length, the charge at the surface of one conductor will be of  opposite sign with the other conductor.